# TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'input' has DataType float64 not in list of allowed values: float16, bfloat16, float32

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I have read many questions similar to mine, but all of them are different with mine.

```
for itr in xrange(MAX_ITERATION):
            train_images, train_annotations = train_dataset_reader.next_batch(batch_size)

#            train_images=tf.image.convert_image_dtype(train_images,np.float32) 
#            train_annotations=tf.image.convert_image_dtype(train_annotations,np.float32) 
#            print(train_images_.get_shape(),train_annotations_.get_shape())
#            train_images=tf.cast(train_images,tf.float32)   
#            train_images = tf.to_float(train_images)
#            train_annotations = tf.to_float(train_annotations)
            #train_images, train_annotations = py_func(selftrans, [train_images_, train_annotations_], [tf.float32], grad=None)
            print(train_images.dtype)
#            train_annotations=tf.cast(train_annotations,tf.float32)
#            train_images,train_annotations = sess.run([train_images,train_annotations])
#            train_images = train_images.astype('float32')
#            train_annotations = train_annotations.astype('float32')
#            print(train_annotations.dtype)
            feed_dict = {image: train_images, annotation: train_annotations, keep_probability: 1}

            sess.run(train_op, feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

The question is: After I use my own data (vessel segmentation, which is a Two Classification Problems), the data read by using next_batch is float64, while `feed_dict()` needs float32. Commonly, codes like  `tf.cast or tf.tp_float` can be used to convert my data to float32. However, after using those converting codes, I found the error changed to **TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, numpy ndarrays, or TensorHandles.** 
Finally, I tried to use sess.run to off-set its tf.Tensor form. Erorr changed to the original one, which means my data was converted back to float64.
**Thus, it seems to be an endless loop.** "Without converting, float64 will not be accepted. After converting, Tf. Tensor will also not be accepted. To off-set the tf.Tensor form using sess run, data will be converted back to float64 simultaneously" How can I fix this? I am looking forward to your reply !**The similar question is here,** [TensorFlow TypeError: Value passed to parameter input has DataType uint8 not in list of allowed values: float16, float32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44822999/tensorflow-typeerror-value-passed-to-parameter-input-has-datatype-uint8-not-in?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Comment: What are types of `train_images` and `train_annotations`? Are they `numpy` arrays? If so just convert their type using `numpy` functions: `feed_dict = {image: train_images.astype(np.float32), ...}`

Comment: @dm0_  I think they are tf.float64. I have tried  `.astype(np.float32)` in fourth and fifth line from the end. The error is : `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'astype'`. I have tried many method to convert them, which are commented out and you can refer to them, as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is caused by my configuration environment. Once I installed my environment as told ([enter link description here](https://github.com/shekkizh/FCN.tensorflow)), the code becomes feasible.

Comment: Many unnecessary errors are caused by my formal environment.